# How to find circle references in a big spring project?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I just updated the spring version of a big Java project, and it reports me some warning like:

> WARN org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addResponseInterceptor' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'httpClient' while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpClient': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

I found in the code, there are a lot of classes use annotation `@Autowired` to inject dependencies, there must be something wrong there.

But since there are too many classes (more than 50), it's really hard for me to find where is wrong. I've working on this several hours, still not found the reason.

Is there any way to make it possible to resolve the problem easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html). In the website it says that show indications for Dependency Injection Cycles within your project. I haven't used it to be honest.

Good luck